# ANCOVA (or other model) with non-parametric data distributions in R?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-comparisons, ancova

I am working with a dataset collected from human subjects that has 46 continuous dependent variables, one categorical independent variable with four groups (n = 20-30 per group), and three covariates (age, sex, and race). I am interested in determining which dependent variables are significantly changed between groups, accounting for the possibility that age, sex, or race may be independently associated with changes in the dependent variables and also correcting for multiple hypothesis testing.

I have been reading about ANCOVA, and it seems that it might fit my needs, but that it assumes that data are sampled from a normal distribution. None of my continuous variables are normally distributed (as evaluated by histograms, qq plots, and normality tests), so I wasn't sure if it would still be acceptable to use (some resources say with sample sizes >20, it's less important to check normality distributions).  Log2 transforming my data moves the distributions closer to normal, but many are still non-normal/skewed.

If a continuous variable is significantly different between groups, I would also like to do post hoc testing to determine between which groups the comparison is significant, but again, it seems that post hoc tests typically used with ANCOVA (glht(mcp) etc)are those used for normally distributed data.

I would appreciate any pointers or ideas the community is able to provide, or any R packages! I haven't given example data because this is more of a theoretical question rather than code implementation, but happy to provide if asked.

Comment: Exactly which variables are not normal? Two common mistakes are to think that the predictor variables or the pooled distribution of $y$ have to be normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the site!

A few things:

Your variables do not need to be normally distributed - the ANOVA/ANCOVA and other gaussian linear models just assume that *the errors* are normally distributed. That is, the noises that is left over after you fit the model.

However, if you have 40 continuous variables and you intend to perform individual ANOVA tests for each then you will have serious issue with the family wise error rate - corrections are absolutely possible but you would it would probably be diluted to the point of meaninglessness, especially with post-hoc comparisons. You might be better off with some kind of multivariate analouge of an ANOVA (e.g. MANOVA, or PERMANOVA), although this comes with the catch that you will only get one p-value and it won't be clear which variables differ.

Instead, what I would probably recommend is some kind of dimensional compression technique (e.g. Principle Components Analysis) - this will let you reduce the number of dimensions in your data, highlight which variables might have interesting interactions, and then you could still perform a PERMANOVA on the PCA space to see how your groups differ. There are also effective ways to visual the information (e.g. biplots) which can show how the groups differ and their interaction with particular variables.

I hope this helps, but feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Edit:

On the r package front you can use `stats` in R for PCA's - it should be pre-installed as a base package. Also see the `vegan` package, as it has some nice functions for conducting PERMANOVA (e.g. `adonis2` - PERMANOVA and `betadisper` - multivariate assumption checks). Lastly, a PERMANOVA as opposed to a MANOVA, relaxes the assumptions of multivariate normality, if that is an issue.

Comment: Also, a up vote would be appreciated if you found this answer helpful, or a tick if it answered your question!

Comment: Strictly, it is the errors (rather than the residuals) that are assumed to be normal.

Comment: Thank you! I was sloppy with my language and I have amended accordingly!

Comment: Also, it is the conditional distribution of the errors that is assumed normal. Many people use the marginal empirical distribution of the residuals to check the assumption, but this method fails. Example: with highly discrete Y data, this distribution appears continuous.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment André.B and everyone else - very helpful and makes a lot of sense! Like Dave and you said, I was mistakenly thinking that the predictor variables had to be normally distributed. Thanks for the suggestions about alternative analyses -- I'll definitely explore them!